# On submission it is giving runtime_error

Tags: runtime-error

```py
t=int(input())

while t>0 :

    c=0

    n,h,y1,y2,e = list(map(int, input().split()))
    for i in range(n):

        x0,x1 = list(map(int, input().split()))    
        if x0==1 :
            if x1 < h-y1:
                e -= 1
        else :
            if y2 < x1 :
                e -= 1
        if e>0 :
            c+=1    
        else :
            break
    print(c)

    t-=1
```

It is passing the sample test cases but on submission, it is showing runtime error(NZEC) occurred.

Here is the link to the question: https://www.codechef.com/problems/PIPSQUIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're reading the inputs and processing them simultaneously. So, a situation can arise in some test cases such that `e<=0` but you still have some `x0 x1` to read(i.e. `i<n-1`). In such cases, you'll `break` the loop because `e<=0` and in next iteration of `while` loop, you'll try to read 5 values `n,h,y1,y2,e = list(map(int, input().split()))` but you'll receive only 2 values `x0 x1` and hence it'll throw a `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 2)` and hence it'll not pass all the test cases.

To fix this, just take all inputs first and then process them according to your current logic.

```py
t=int(input())

while t>0 :

    c=0

    n,h,y1,y2,e = list(map(int, input().split()))
    inputs = []
    for i in range(n):
        inputs.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
    for inp in inputs:

        x0,x1 = inp
        if x0==1 :
            if x1 < h-y1:
                e -= 1
        else :
            if y2 < x1 :
                e -= 1
        if e>0 :
            c+=1
        else :
            break
    print(c)

    t -= 1
```

Comment: Thanks!I got it.

Comment: I am getting wrong answer,I rectified that but Can u tell me where am I doing wrong in my logic
link to my code :
https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/29126544

Comment: Okay, you have `h-y1==x1` condition in your code submission(https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/29126544). It should be `h-y1<=x1` because, if `h-y1` is less than or equals to `x1`, the person can easily pass the barrier.